# Add inline css style to JHTML_ (joomla) object

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I don't have a lot of experience with Joomla and I'm sure how this will be a really simple question to someone who was work in Joomla before.

I'm working on existing project where I need to add inline css style to  elements which are created on this way:

```
JHTML::_('grid.sort', $name[$id], 'a.'.$name[$id], $this->listDirn, $this->listOrder)
```

So I need something like this:

```
JHTML::_('grid.sort', $name[$id], 'a.'.$name[$id], $this->listDirn, $this->listOrder, 'style: height 500px; color: blue;')
```

Thanks in advance

Every kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: Why use inline css? Why not just add to .css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to pass styles to the sort element directly as you can see here in the code
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/html/grid.php#L74.

What you can do is to add the style on the document directly:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addStyleDeclaration('#myelement {height 500px; color: blue;}');
```

perhaps you want to add `!important` to the style to enforce it.